# Store Facebook ID to Firebase using dialogflow inline editor

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

Hi I have created a fb chatbot using dialogflow which saves specific user inputs to firebase . Is there a way to also store the fb id of the user in firebase . heres what I've got so far.

```
  function getNameHandler(agent) {
    let code = agent.parameters.code ;
   // let user_id = agent["outputContexts"][0]["parameters"]["facebook_sender_id"];

    db.collection("codes").add({ code: code});

    agent.add(`Please wait for the response for code : ${code}`);
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the messenger_id you have to used this code:

let user_id = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.sender.id;

```
function handler(agent){
    
      let user_id = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.sender.id;
    
      return admin.database().ref('/spo').push({user_id :user_id}).then((snapshot) => {
     
      agent.add(`Thank you. `);
    });
     
    
   }
```